# Bootstrap Form Helpers country picker doesn't get serialized

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, select, serialization, helper

I have a country picker in my form like this:

```
<select class="bfh-countries text-left" name="country" id="country" data-country="DE">  
</select>
```

I can get the value with jQuery like this:

```
$("#country").val()
```

but when i try to serialize the form with `$("#myform").serializeArray()` The value for "country" is an empty string.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this problem and it took me forever to find because there aren't any examples of it. What you really want to do is use data-name="country", which names the hidden variable on the back end as country. For the country picker, you can use the div tag as follows:

```
<div class="country bfh-selectbox bfh-countries" data-flags="true" data-filter="true" data-name="country" data-country="POSTBACK_VARIABLE_GOES_HERE"></div>
```

If you do this, you'll find a hidden variable that's added to the page as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" name="country" value="US">
```

The value above assumes you selected United States but it is entered as a 2 character code, which could then be entered as data-country above if you need to do server-side validation and display the page again without forcing the user to select the value all over again.

This was seriously a nightmare to find.